# Highcharts Parallel Coordinates: Hover/Highlight all series through point

Tags: highcharts

I implemented a [parallel coordinates chart](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/parallel-coordinates) in highchart and already activated hovering.

However, most of the times there is more than one serie lines on the same point (= value of a category) For instance, in the example linked above, there could be multiple lines on shoes=Adidas). When hovering this point, I would like to examine all series lines going through this point and not only the one on the top, e.g. I want to see, how Adidas shoes correlate with other categories (or at least see, wether there is some correlation).

I guess, basically I am looking for something like hover all lines in this point at once or even better: switch between all lines while hovering this point. Any idea how I could do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a cool feature, I suggest to create an idea on [UserVoice](https://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api) and vote for it, so this will come out of the box.

Here is simple implementation: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/or57kpyx/14/

Snippet:

(**Note**: replaced `series.events.mouseOver` with `series.point.events.mouseOver`, so we know exact value of the point currently hovering):

```
      point: {
        events: {
          mouseOver: function() {
            var series = this.series.chart.series, // all series on the chart
              x = this.x,
              y = this.y;

            Highcharts.each(series, function (s) {
                // The same parallel coords
              if (s.data[x].y === y) {
                s.group.toFront();
                s.setState('hover');
              } else {
                s.setState('');
              }
            });
          }
        }
      }
```